# Is there a way to use regular expression to format kendo grid column?

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I want to format my kendo grid column with a regular expression. Now I have data like `1-st0001_Green`. I want to format this data like `st0001`. So basically I want data inside `-` and `_`. I have written a regular expression to extract data inside `-` and `_`. My kendo grid is generating dynamically based on `form date` and `to date` so column name is not fixed. I am trying below code to use template and format function.

```
var options = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").getOptions();
for (i = 0; i < options.columns.length; i++) {    
options.columns[i].template = "#= FormatValue(" + options.columns[i].field + ")#";
}
```

`FormatValue` function is below

```
function FormatValue(value) {
    var regExp = /(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\_)/;   //if i execute this expression on string i get value inside - and _
    return kendo.toString(value, regExp)
   // here some how i want to use the regExp to format kendo grid column value
}
```

So in this `FormatValue` function i want to apply the regular expression to all my column value. If anything else i can do here to get value between `-` and `_` then please suggest some link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i used below format function which gave me output inside `-` and `_`

```
function FormatValue(value) {
    let regex = new RegExp(/(?<=\-)(.*?)(?=\_)/);
    var result = value.replace(value, regex.exec(value));
    str = result.split(',')[0];
    return str;
}
```